# Inserting character dynamically into contentediatble div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to insert some character dynamically in contenteditable repeatly. Means once I press button character get inserted than again when I press button character get inserted after the previous one but from below code it just reinsert on same again and again.

**Jquery**

`````````````````````````````
function myFunc(){
$('#test').html('````````````````````````````');
}
`````````````````````````````

**HTML**

```
<div id="test" contenteditable="true"></div>

<button onclick="myFunc()">CLICK</button>
```

Comment: you have to preserve current `html` and than append new `html` `.html()` replace all stuff inside div do something like `$('#test').html($('#test').html() + '````````````````````````````');` or `.append()`

Comment: You ca use as $('#test').append('````````````````````````````');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

`````````````````````````````
function myFunc() {
  $('#test').html($('#test').html()+'````````````````````````````');
}
`````````````````````````````

[Here is the **JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/2mcvb6f6/)

But if you want it to also add a new line, use `<br/>` like so:

`````````````````````````````
function myFunc() {
  $('#test').html($('#test').html()+'````````````````````````````<br/>');
}
`````````````````````````````

[Here is the second **demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/z87jxzj7/)

Answer (score 1):

you are rewriting the html of the element each time try appending it like this `$('#test').append('a')`

Answer (score 1):

`````````````````````````````js
function myFunc(){
$('#test').append('````````````````````````````');
}
`````````````````````````````

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" contenteditable="true"></div>

<button onclick="myFunc()">CLICK</button>
```

Instead of using .html() you need to use append() as you were appending new text to your html, .html() will replace the previous text.